# Why does order of sub document query affect results in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am querying against a collection with:

```
> db.things.find({ "entity":{entityType:"Location", id: "26802"}})
```

which returns 0 results, but if I query with the `entityType` and `id` switched:

```
> db.things.find({ "entity":{id: "26802", entityType:"Location"}})
```

3 results are returned.

3 results are also returned for both of:

```
> db.things.find({ "entity.id": "26802", "entity.entityType":"Location"})
> db.things.find({ "entity.entityType":"Location", "entity.id": "26802"})
```

why is this?

There is an index on `entity`

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "entity" : 1
    },
    "name" : "entity_1",
    "ns" : "db_name.things"
}
```

Comment: just found documentation about it, not a bug. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-subdocuments, but I still don't understand why this would be useful/unsurprising behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-exact-matches-on-embedded-documents),

This query, `entity` field must match the embedded document exactly.

```
> db.things.find({ "entity":{entityType:"Location", id: "26802"}})
```

**only** match

```
entity: {
    entityType:"Location", 
    id: "26802"
}
```

rather than this object

```
entity: {
    id: "26802"
    entityType:"Location", 
}
```

However, Those two queries below could match the above two objects, because this query matches the document where the `entity` field contains an embedded document with the field `id` with the value `"26802"` and a field `entityType` with the value `"Location"`.

```
> db.things.find({ "entity.id": "26802", "entity.entityType":"Location"})
> db.things.find({ "entity.entityType":"Location", "entity.id": "26802"})
```